# Generating AJAX callback- table on a javascript popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have used jquery ajax which initiates on click of a button , and on click of it a variable passes to the php script that the jquery post is using. However when i try to append the return data on javascript alert() method it returns the php script's html contents instead rather than rendering it out. Can anyone assit me on this?

```
<?php

$var = $_POST['var'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from racers Where style = '$var'");


while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
    $name = $r['rName'];

    echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: post your php code please

Comment: post the contents it displayed (cause it varies)

Comment: If you print html in an `alert()` of course what you will see are the html tags.

Comment: @digzol really ?!!?! I thought it was going to runt he html then produce it out on the alert.......how can generate out html into like a popup , i thought alert was the best way....any advice?!?!?!

Comment: you have syntax error... check my answer below. As for Popup, that should be another question entirely

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Apache (as most of the PHP configs do). 
Did you check your Apache configuration. I guess it must be configured to process PHP's as scripts. Otherwise it returns it as it is without parsing

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, try this;

```
<?php

   $var = $_POST['var'];

   $sql = mysql_query("select * from racers Where style = '$var'");


while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
 {
   $name = $r['rName'];

   echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>';
 }
?>
```

change sql_query to mysql_query